# Scala - How to save Trait's names in a collection?

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to build something to control the mixing of `Traits`. How can I save, for example, the `Trait`'s names in a collection, say in a `Map` or `List` as `String` values?

This is something that I can do with Classes, instantiating them by their names using dynamic class loading.

### My Edit:

For example: I have this

```
val order =  new Order with Bonus with Discount
```

with 'a tool' - I was thinking to have/create something that will help the user to do only the right mixing. What I mean "the right mixing"? If somebody do this mixing:

```
val order =  new Order with Bonus with Discount with Bonus 
//should be wrong, based on my rules
```

and so on..., I need to say for example that the `Discount` cannot be mixed before the `Bonus` like this:

```
val order =  new Order with Discount with Bonus //wrong, based on my rules
```

I need to say that `an order` cannot be without a `Bonus`, like:

```
val order =  new Order with Discount //wrong
```

but can be without a `Discount`, like:

```
val order =  new Order with Bonus //right
```

So, my idea is to build something and to control these mixings, to define in someway these rules. For my opinion, mixing cannot force/oblige a third party to know what is coded inside a Trait in order to know when and where is alowed to mix it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Mixing in traits is usually a static mechanism, and could result in surprises if done somehow dynamically (because of overriding rules).

Comment: I want to create(find) a way to manage the order of mixing, and to controll it - simple, to put the rules/conditions `who` can be mixed with `whom` and  not to be, exactly, surprised by "the overriding rules" - as you said.
bthw, I have sooo many traits and there isn't logical in my case to put them in a hierachy mood, I have to controll them with a 'tool' from outside :( - this sounds the only logical solution to me!

Comment: Could you update the question to include the problem you're trying to solve instead of trying to find a way to make your solution work? There are other ways to avoid mixing traits that use the Scala type system directly. Some code examples would be helpful too.

Comment: Without more details (what external tool? why do you need to use traits?), I cannot really help you, sorry.

Comment: You can check my Edits up. Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make compiler enforce these rules for you. Consider this:

```
trait Base { def kind: String }
trait Bonus extends Base { override def kind = "bonus" }
trait Discount extends Base { abstract override def kind = "discount" }
trait Order { self: Bonus => }

new Order with Bonus
res0: Order with Bonus = $anon$1@19b4e418 

new Order with Discount
<console>:12: error: illegal inheritance;
self-type Order with Discount does not conform to Order's selftype Order with Bonus     

new Order with Bonus with Discount
res2: Order with Bonus with Discount = $anon$1@13dbf6de

new Order with Discount with Bonus
<console>:12: error: overriding method kind in trait Discount of type => String;
method kind in trait Bonus of type => String needs `abstract override' modifiers
          new Order with Discount with Bonus
```

Two things are going on here: 
`trait Order { self: Bonus => }` means that any class that implements `Order` must also implement `Bonus`.

The ordering is a bit more complicated. `abstract override` modifier is intended to facilitate implementation of [stackable traits](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html), but it has a "side effect", that can be exploited here: a trait, that has a method annotated with `abstract override` can only been mixed in *after* a trait or a class that defines a concrete implementation of that method.

Comment: I am going to check it right now. Seems a promissing way although I was thinking to build a kind of tree and to put some conditions between the traits in the tree hierarchy nodes, ...that's why I was thinking in the beginning how I can "call to mix a trait by it's name if I save it in a String field"